как блочная модель влияет на copy&past текста
после copy&past появляются пустые строки.
ps: можно посмотреть в редакторах, в гугл переводчике и тд.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body style="display: flex; gap: 140px">
    <section class="first">
      <h1>1</h1>
      <span>пустые строки в тексте после copy&past из за flex</span>
      <div style="display: flex"><p style="display: inline-block;">one</p></div>
      <div style="display: flex"><p style="display: inline-block;">two</p></div>
      <div style="display: flex"><p style="display: inline-block;">three</p></div>
    </section>
    <section class="second">
      <h1>2</h1>
      <span>пустые строки в тексте после copy&past из за того что p это блочный элемент</span>
      <div><p>one</p></div>
      <div><p>two</p></div>
      <div><p>three</p></div>
    </section>
    <section class="third">
      <h1>3</h1>
      <span>нет пустых строк после copy&past</span>
      <div><p style="display: inline-block">one</p></div>
      <div><p style="display: inline-block">two</p></div>
      <div><p style="display: inline-block">three</p></div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>




В Firefox все три варианта с одинаковыми пустыми строками

@andreymal в окне пойска? попробуй в редакторе vscode, либо в другом, тут дело не в браузере.

Если не принципиально, то можно убрать из div p и все будет нормально копироваться

@LureRed мне бы в первую очередь понять почему так, да и p сушествует для текста, не думаю что надо писать текст прямо в div

HTML-элемент  представляет собой абзац. Абзацы обычно представлены в визуальной среде в виде блоков текста, отделённых от соседних блоков пустыми строками и/или отступом в первой строке, кроме этого HTML-абзацы могут представлять собой структурную группировку однотипного содержимого, например изображений или полей формы. p можно заменить на span например или действительно писать прямо в div

@LureRed span решает проблему, спасибо за это, но пока что не понял как блочная модель влияет на все это дело. В примерах 1 и 3 допустим визуально не отличить(они отделены), но из за flex 1ый сахраняет отступы после c&p втарой нет. Из за того что я узнал про поведение span, появилось больше вопросов чем ответов) но еще раз спасибо за инфу.

@LureRed основной момент как избавится от отступов в первом примере через css, не трогая flex, и тег p, но осталные моменты тоже интересны

@Armen у тега "p" по умолчанию Хром вставляет margin-top: 1em и margin-bottom: 1em. Убери эти маргины или сделай глобальный стиль для всех "p" - margin: 0 0 10px - это стандарт

И не за чем каждую "p" оборачивать в div. достаточно обернуть все "p" в один div

@ЕвгенийЛи спасибо за советы конечно) но тут дело не в margin-ах я не новичек если что)) это чисто пример, в реале надо оборачивать из за других частей кода)

@LureRed всем  задайте стиль - display: contents !important
